# VLookup in VB returning Error 2042 where VLookup in worksheet returns expected

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to write a function that will lookup a value in a table based on a matching date. In the event of no match it will lookup up to 7 days prior before returning an error.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetWeekEndBalanceFromStatement(lookupDate As Date, statement As Range, column As Integer) As Variant
    Dim lookupModifier As Integer

    Do While IsError(Application.VLookup(DateAdd("d", lookupModifier, lookupDate), statement, column, False)) And lookupModifier > -7
        lookupModifier = lookupModifier - 1
    Loop

    GetWeekEndBalanceFromStatement = Application.VLookup(DateAdd("d", lookupModifier, lookupDate), statement, column, False)
End Function
```

The issue I'm having when I break it down for debugging is the VLookups consistently return

> Error 2042

even in the event an identical VLookup written in the spreadsheet returns a value.

The written function calls for reference, K8 being the first line:

```
=DATE(2018,1,5)
=VLOOKUP(K8, A:F, 6,FALSE )
=GetWeekEndBalanceFromStatement(K8,A:F,6)
```

Any clues as to what I may be doing wrong? I've attempted encapsulating dates in CDate, appending .Value to ranges and bringing in date as a variant and accessing .Value2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running some tests, I recall some issues I faced when using `VLookup` and `Match` with Dates, better use their Excel values (change `Date` to `Double`).

**Modified Function Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetWeekEndBalanceFromStatement(lookupDate As Double, statement As Range, column As Integer) As Variant
    Dim lookupModifier As Integer

    Do While IsError(Application.VLookup(lookupDate + lookupModifier, statement, column, False)) And lookupModifier > -7
        lookupModifier = lookupModifier - 1
    Loop

    GetWeekEndBalanceFromStatement = Application.VLookup(lookupDate + lookupModifier, statement, column, False)
End Function
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion but resolved it by wrapping the dateadd function in clng as dates have no decimal portion.

Comment: Yes, I believe the problem is that Excel does not have a **Date** data type.  VBA does.  And `VLOOKUP` is sensitive to the particular data type.  So one has to ensure that the comparison is between values of the same data type.